# Improving scrolling for a Horizontal RecyclerView inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a `ListView` item. Everything seems to be fine, but the scrolling of the horizontal `RecyclerView` is a crapshoot - sometimes the `ListView` scrolls instead, even though the fling is more horizontal than vertical. Prior to this, I used `HListView`, which was basically a reoriented `ListView`, and that worked just fine.

So my question is, is there a way to improve scrolling in this situation? Note that I'm aware of the *faux-pas*s, problems and evils of nesting multiple scrollviews, so no need to point that out ;)

Comment: I am having the same issue did you get any solution?

Comment: i am also having the same issue, even i replaced listview with recyclerview but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

in that case use can use nestedscroll in your inner view

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Horizontal RecyclerView in Vertical RecyclerView. Your problem will be solved.